# I create a default marker at MAP initialization but Marker not showing Content? What can I Do for it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I want to place marker at time of initializing map marker is pointed
but content of infowindow not showing, Itried same code with JSFiddle.net its working there.
Is it any problem with google map key

```js
function initialize()
{
 var map;
 var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(18.527362399999998,73.8783206); 
 var mapProp = {
   center:myCenter,
    zoom:10,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
  addMarker(myCenter, 'Center of Map', map,"gg");
}


function addMarker(latlng,title,map,info){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            zoom:12,
            title: title,
            draggable:true
    });

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          //creating new infowindow
     infowindow.close();//hide the infowindow
       infowindow.setContent('Latitude: '); 
     infowindow.open(map,marker);

}
```

```html
<html>
  <body onload="initialize()"  style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
<div id="mapDiv" style="display: none;">
        <p>        
          <input type="text" size="60" id="mapAdd" name="address" />
          <input type="button" name="getLocation" value="Get Location" onclick="closeMap();"/>
         </p>
        <input type="text" id="lat"/>
        <input type="text" id="lng"/>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to close the infowindow you've just created... it won't be open until you call open on it.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this -

You have *not* used `info` variable while creating `InfoWindow`

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
'content' : info
);
```

But I can see you have used `setContent`, please check z-index of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

1. you aren't including the Google Maps Javascript API v3
2. your map doesn't have a size

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize()
{
 var map;
 var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(18.527362399999998,73.8783206); 
 var mapProp = {
   center:myCenter,
    zoom:10,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
  addMarker(myCenter, 'Center of Map', map,"gg");
}


function addMarker(latlng,title,map,info){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            zoom:12,
            title: title,
            draggable:true
    });

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          //creating new infowindow
     infowindow.close();//hide the infowindow
       infowindow.setContent('Latitude: '); 
     infowindow.open(map,marker);

}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <body onload="initialize()"  style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
<div id="mapDiv">
        <p>        
          <input type="text" size="60" id="mapAdd" name="address" />
          <input type="button" name="getLocation" value="Get Location" onclick="closeMap();"/>
         </p>
        <input type="text" id="lat"/>
        <input type="text" id="lng"/>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px; width:500px;"></div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```